# iOS app store submission rejected for "App-Prefs:root=WIFI"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently a client submitted his app but was rejected by Apple:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change.
>
> app-prefs:root=wifi
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the
>   associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality
>   using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

I tried to search for relevant code/setting and the only thing I can find is:

```
[alertView setBlockSure:^{
    NSString * urlString = @"App-Prefs:root=WIFI";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}];
```

And there is no entry under target -> info -> URL Types.

So what is the issue? I read somewhere on Stackoverflow, accessing to WiFi setting directly from an app is considered private? But I can't find recent Apple documentation for valid ones. If not we'll consider opening to just setting instead.

Comment: Use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`.

Comment: So it is not supported to go directly into Wifi page then? Thanks.

Comment: Where can I get a list of supported URLs?